# Как получить текст из строки в python

Tags: python, строки

Есть переменная с данными:

```
text = """<div class="image" style="background-image: url('https://test_link.com/item/USP-S+%7C+Monster+Mashup+%28Battle-Scarred%29/100.png');"></div>"""
```

И мне необходимо получить текст от `url('` до `');">` как это можно сделать?

Comment: `print(text.split("'")[1]) `

Comment: @Danis Нет, это между любыми кавычками ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import re
text = """<div class="image" style="background-image: url('https://test_link.com/item/USP-S+%7C+Monster+Mashup+%28Battle-Scarred%29/100.png');"></div>"""
res = re.findall("url\(\'(.*?)\'\);\">", text)
```

```
text = """<div class="image" style="background-image: url('https://test_link.com/item/USP-S+%7C+Monster+Mashup+%28Battle-Scarred%29/100.png');"></div>"""
text[text.find("url('")+5:text.find("');\">")]
```

Comment: А можно без регулярок?)

Comment: @MaximChyorny Я тоже их недолюбливаю XD. Подумаю, просто это первое в голову пришло XD

Comment: @MaximChyorny Обновил